# Newest version of readr gives error :Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, installation, package, tidyverse, readr

I've seen a thread about my issue on stackoverflow and reddit but all the solutions I read are not working for me. I have the latest version of readr and R but I still get the same error when using the function `read_delim`. I also have tidyverse installed.

Has anyone managed to find another solution?
This is the output of my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape_0.8.8   openxlsx_4.2.4  readxl_1.3.1    lubridate_1.8.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7    
 [8] purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.7    ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0 reshape2_1.4.4   haven_2.3.1      colorspace_2.0-0 vctrs_0.3.8      generics_0.1.0  
 [7] utf8_1.1.4       rlang_1.0.2      pillar_1.7.0     glue_1.4.2       withr_2.3.0      DBI_1.1.0       
[13] bit64_4.0.5      dbplyr_2.1.1     modelr_0.1.8     lifecycle_1.0.0  plyr_1.8.6       munsell_0.5.0   
[19] gtable_0.3.0     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_1.0.2      zip_2.1.1        tzdb_0.1.2       parallel_4.2.0  
[25] fansi_0.4.1      broom_0.8.0      Rcpp_1.0.5       scales_1.1.1     backports_1.4.1  vroom_1.5.7     
[31] jsonlite_1.8.0   fs_1.5.0         bit_4.0.4        hms_1.1.1        stringi_1.5.3    grid_4.2.0      
[37] cli_3.3.0        tools_4.2.0      magrittr_2.0.1   crayon_1.5.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3  ellipsis_0.3.2  
[43] xml2_1.3.2       reprex_2.0.1     assertthat_0.2.1 httr_1.4.2       rstudioapi_0.13  R6_2.5.0        
[49] compiler_4.2.0
```

I hope someone can help..

Example:

```
structure(list(id_patient = 16397:16406, id_patient_crf = c(281007L, 
281009L, 281011L, 281013L, 281015L, 281017L, 281019L, 281021L, 
281023L, 281025L), seq_id = 1:10, crf_label = c("vaccinatiegegevens", 
"vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens", 
"vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens", 
"vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens", "vaccinatiegegevens"
), X1414 = c(10L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

If you write this away as a csv file:

```
write.table(test, file = 'test.csv', sep= ";")
```

and then open it again with this code:

```
read_delim(file = testfilelocation, delim = ";")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Does it happen with all input files or just certain ones? The error itself doesn't seem like it's coming from `readr` directly. More likely it's `cli` or something else. But without being able to reproduce the error it's really tough to provide any sort of specific help.

Comment: Hello @MrFlick, I added an edit to my original post. i hope this helps. If you need anything else, please let me know

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with that example. How are you running R. Are you using RGUI or RStudio? What version of the GUI are you using?

Comment: I am using Rstudio version 4.2.0

Comment: That's your R version number, not RStudio. The RStudio version number is very different.

Comment: my apologies, this is my Rstudio version: RStudio
2022.02.2 Build 485
© 2009-2022 RStudio, PBC
"Prairie Trillium" Release (8acbd38b, 2022-04-19) for Windows